# Backbone: How to set the right container and handle the changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone doesn't come with any clear pattern about how to build an application. I'm experiencing some difficulties right now. In the following picture, I am visually and in a simplified manner, describing what I want to get.

I have a list of tasks. I want to have the due date listed after the tasks that happen to have the same due date. The dates also ordered chronologically.

One approach I decided to take is to have:

- A collection of dates and a view for each date
- A collection of tasks and a sub view (parent view is the date view) for each task

In your view, is this a good approach of the problem?

Potential problems when keeping up to date:

- If I change the date, I want the date container to reposition itself so that they are chronologically (**re-fetch all the date collections?**)
- If I change the due date of a task, I want the task to move to the right date container (**remove its view and re-fetch all the task collections?**)
- If another user changes a task I want it to be reflected (**is fetch the appropriate thing to do?**)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this a good approach of the problem?

**Yes!**: CollectionView -> (n)ModelViews (as deep as needed)

> If I change the date, I want the date container to reposition itself so that they are chronologically (re-fetch all the date collections?)

You always have to send the changes to the server, but you don't need to *re-fetch* anything, you already have the data in you hand, you can just *re-render*. The optimization of this re-render depends in a lot of details.

> If I change the due date of a task, I want the task to move to the right date container (remove its view and re-fetch all the task collections?)

Again you don't need to ask for data. Just remove the changed Task from the actual DateContainer collection and add it to the collection of the new DateContainer. Make the DateContainers to respond to this `add/remove` event.

> If another user changes a task I want it to be reflected (is fetch the appropriate thing to do?)

Well, this is a very opened question. As you say you can re-fetch the whole data every X seconds. Or you can implement an optimized `updated_elements` request in your API and ask for it each X seconds. Or you can go by the WebSockets way.

Comment: May you elaborate a bit? How do you envision the `updated_elements` request? What should it return?

Comment: This should be a complex pattern of your architecture. You should define a way to have a record of all the changes in your database and be able to encapsulate them in a _json_ format. The request can be something like: `updated_elements?since=123` where `123` is the last change your front-side application has knowledge of. Then in your front-side you have to implement a system to _digest_ these changes.